# How to retrieve the foreign key as a number in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys

I have two related tables called **Budget** and **Client**. The **Budget**'s `client` field is the foreign key that stores the  **Client**'s id. Symfony2 does something that when I print in a twig template the `client` field, it automatically shows the `name` of the **Client** table. How can I make it retrieve the identifier/number of the foreign key, accessing this `client` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've provided [Getters & Setters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters) for your Entity Classes, it should be as simple as:

```
{{ client.id }}
```

Comment: I am looping over a variable `budgets` that lists all the Budgets in a twig template like `{% for b in budgets %}`. If I call `b.client`, it prints the Client name, not the foreign key NUMBER. I don't have access to the Client table at this moment. Get it?

Comment: Got it ... try `b.client.id`